# Azure application logging not working from website

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a number of Azure websites (10) with the same code. Inside the Global.asax in Application_error I have some simple logging code, the crucial line of which is:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(err)
```

Where `err` is a `string`.

I've set each website to log errors straight to table storage, but my problem is that only some of them actually work. The ones that work seem fine and I can generate new entries into the storage tables by simulating an error, but randomly some of the sites just refuse to log anything at all.

I've republished all 10 sites to make sure they are all running the most recent code. They are all using the same subscription, and all appear to have the same application logging setting on (each pointing to their own table, all of which exist).

I've also tried live streaming and the same ones that fail to log in the tables fail to stream anything either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For the websites that you dont see logs, is it just this specific error log from global.asax or are you not seeing any logs?

Comment: I just added a generic handler which runs `System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("Test log entry")` to test it and still nothing so it's not just the global.asax. I also triple checked the settings in Azure and it's definitely pointing to the table that I'm looking at.

Comment: Try following this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157442/enable-azure-website-application-diagnostics/28161288#28161288

Comment: Thanks Amit but it's not an MVC app - it's a vb.Net webforms app.